# How to specify the expected java class when there are two same-name class in different dependency packages?

Tags: java, eclipse, deployment

I'm coding in my current package, and take two packages/project as the dependencies which are named as package-A and package-B.

In package-A, there is an java class: "com.xx.cc.java"
and in package-B, there is an same-name java class: "com.xx.cc.java"
(fields and function in these two java class are different)

I want to import the "com.xx.cc.java" in package-A, however, eclipse would automatically import the "com.xx.cc.java" in package-B,  I'm really boring about it and have no idea.

Is there anyway to specify the package in which I want to import the java class ?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: You mean that you import these packages from 2 different jars, right?

Comment: Yeah, from 2 different jars, and I have no permission to change any of them.

Comment: only thing what i can think off is to change order of your libraries in project properties, but i'm not sure will this work, to be honest, im not sure is using two libraries which implements same class in same pachage with different functionality is good idea in first place

Comment: @user902383 the order of jars won't matter, the problem will be there. But as you said in the end, having this mess is not a good idea.

Comment: you can actually try load your class on runtime from specified jar file/project, that might work

Comment: I'm really suffering with the mess design, however, I have no permission to change any of them.

Comment: @user902383 Both of these two packages are required to me, does it matter the usage of them from your idea ?

Comment: OT: The architects or designers of this application should come here and have a talk with us :). Basically, there's no way to solve it unless you load/unload classes at runtime, but this is a really bad design and should be avoided.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza  Bad news, but, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Theoretically you can solve this problem using different class loaders for each one of the libraries. But you cannot put both into application class path. At least one of them should be beyond the regular application classpath and you should implement access to it using your custom class loader.

How to solve this in eclipse? You can create 2 projects. One of them depends on library A, other on library B. The "other" project will implement the custom class loader that I have already mentioned.

BUT: do you really need this? What are these strange libraries that put different classes to the same package? This situation sounds bad from the beginning.

Comment: Seems it's the only way. Marked it as answer.

Answer (score 0):

You are simply going to have difficult to determine behavior at runtime when there are multiple classes with the same fully qualified name. You can attempt to control the order of jars/resources on the classpath. However, it sounds like perhaps you are running in an osgi environment, where you have very little control over order of items on class path.

Comment: Correct, especially after deployment, and I get a wrong result.

Comment: This simply is not going to work. These projects /MUST/ be refactored to avoid conflicting fully qualified class names.

Answer (score -2):

Yes, there is a way to access the classes with same name lying in different packages.

Let assume `class A` in `package1` and `package2`. Then to access the two `classes A` in another class, do as follows:

- Import the two packages: `package1` & `package2`
- Use the classes as `package1.A` & `package2.A`

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Thanks Abhishek, however, the package path of these two class are the same, so it doesn't work.

Comment: Read the question + comments. The classes have the *exact same* fully-qualified name.

Comment: jjs I still can't get your question exactly. Can you please clarify it.

Comment: Hello jjs, you want to access the class with a certain name in one dependency package without using or importing the class with same qualified name present in other dependency package, right?

Comment: Sorry for late response. I have two dependency package(jars) A and B, Both of package A and package B have java class named as com.example.a.java, that means, if I want to import this class from package A, I need to code "import com.example.a;", it is absolutely same with the importing from package B. It's not stable. That's why there is this question.